как исключить слой для шейдера Unity URP?
в функции URP ассета
[System.Serializable]
    public class CustomPassSettings
    {
        public RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.BeforeRenderingPostProcessing;
        public int screenHeight = 144;

        public LayerMask excludeLayer;
    }

в excludeLayer указывается слой который нужно исключать
можете объяснить как сделать его исключение в функции, то есть чтобы шейдер применялся ко всем кроме этого слоя...
public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get();
        using (new ProfilingScope(cmd, new ProfilingSampler("Pixelize Pass")))
        {
           
            Blit(cmd, colorBuffer, pixelBuffer, material);
            Blit(cmd, pixelBuffer, colorBuffer);
        }

        context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
        CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
    }

